# Autocomplete doesn't work anymore

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, autocomplete

A few days I made with my teacher a autocomplete input!

Now I try to test it again, but it suddenly doesn't work anymore!

My teacher is now gona for a while so I have to try it alone.
But I just don't know how to fix this.(Yes I realy tried it.)
It does give a `$_GET`.(So that is not the problem)

The JQuery:

```
var element = '';
function split( val ) {
 return val.split( /,\s*/ );
}
function extractLast( term ) {
 return split( term ).pop();
}
function getSearchlocation( ) {
 return $(element).data('searchlocation');
}

$( ".tag" ).bind( "keydown", function( event ) {
 if ( event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
     $( this ).autocomplete( "instance" ).menu.active ) {
     event.preventDefault();
 }
})
.autocomplete({
 source: function( request, response ) {
     $.getJSON( 'checklistHandler.php', {
         term: extractLast( request.term ),
         searchlocation: getSearchlocation(  )
     }, response );
 },
 search: function() {
     var term = extractLast( this.value );
     element = this;
     if ( term.length < 2 ) {
         return false;
     }
 },
 focus: function() {
     return false;
     },
 select: function( event, ui ) {
     var terms = split( this.value );
     terms.pop();
     terms.push( ui.item.value );
     terms.push( "" );
     this.value = terms.join( ", " );
     return false;
 }
});
```

The Handler:

```
if ($_GET['term']) {
    if($_GET['searchlocation']=='cursus')
    {
        $table = 'flexibel';
        $column = 'app';
    }
    elseif($_GET['searchlocation']=='boek')
    {
        $table = 'boeken';
        $column = 'naam';
    }
    else
    {
        exit;
    }

$search = $_GET['term'];

$query = mysql_query("SELECT ".$column." FROM ".$table." WHERE ".$column." LIKE '%".$search."%'");
$result = array();

$i=0;
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
    $result[] = array('id'=>$i, 'label'=>$r[$column], 'value'=>$r[$column]);
    $i++;
}

echo json_encode($result);
```

}

The Input:

```
if ($onderdeel['formInputType'] == 'autocomplete')
{
    ?>
    <tr>
        <input type="hidden" name="buildingblock[<?=$onderdeel['formBuildingBlockId']?>][formBuildingBlockId]" value="<?=$onderdeel['formBuildingBlockId']?>">
        <td class="<?= $class ?>" width="320" style="vertical-align: middle;"><?= $onderdeel['formInputLabel'] ?><?=($onderdeel['formRequired'] == 'on' ? '<img title="Verplicht Veld" alt="Verplicht Veld" style="position: relative; top: -10px; height: 5px; width: 5px;" src="'.IMG.'/asterisk_orange.png">' : '')?></td>
        <td class="<?= $class ?>" width="320"><textarea style="min-width: 212px; max-width: 212px;" class="tag" data-searchlocation="<?=$onderdeel['formInputOptions']?>" name="buildingblock[<?=$onderdeel['formBuildingBlockId']?>][content]" <?=($onderdeel['formRequired'] == 'on' ? 'required' : '')?>><?=$onderdeel['formContent']?></textarea></td>
        <td class="<?= $class ?>" width="60" style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: center;"><input type="checkbox" name="buildingblock[<?=$onderdeel['formBuildingBlockId']?>][checked]" value="1"<?= ($onderdeel['formContentChecked'] == 1 ? ' checked="checked"' : '') ?> /></td>
        <td class="<?= $class ?>" width="60" style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: center;"><a href="checklistHandler.php?delete_vraag=<?=$test?>"></a></td>
    </tr>
<?
}
```

The response op the request is:
`[{"id":0,"label":"Excel Basis","value":"Excel Basis"},{"id":1,"label":"Excel Essentials","value":"Excel Essentials"},{"id":2,"label":"Excel Gevorderd","value":"Excel Gevorderd"},{"id":3,"label":"Excel: Analyse en Rapportage","value":"Excel: Analyse en Rapportage"},{"id":4,"label":"Excel: Draaitabellen en Grafieken","value":"Excel: Draaitabellen en Grafieken"},{"id":5,"label":"Excel: Functies en Formules","value":"Excel: Functies en Formules"},{"id":6,"label":"Excel: Koppelingen en Macro\u2019s ","value":"Excel: Koppelingen en Macro\u2019s "},{"id":7,"label":"Flexibele cursussen","value":"Flexibele cursussen"},{"id":8,"label":"Word: Complexe Documenten","value":"Word: Complexe Documenten"}]`

I Hope you can help me what the problem is.

Greets,

Mathieu.

Comment: what errors do you get, in your browsers developer console as well as on the page itself?

Comment: None that is the problem. It says it all goes well!

Comment: So what isn't working, specify. What do you want to happen what isn't happening.

Comment: That when you type 3 letters like `Exc` then there need come a list of items that I get from the DB and put it in a list!

Comment: Looks vulnerable for sql injections, have a look at [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) too.

Comment: The `$_GET` does give you the value `'Exc'` when you type that in?

Comment: Yes! It does. That is where I strugle

Comment: Do a `var_dump()` on your `$result` to check what that returns.

Comment: It doesn't return anything. So it doens't give any response!

Comment: So do the same thing with `$r` in your `while` loop to see if there is something wrong with your query or your database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem Resolved!

Problem was...

I asked the wrong data from the DB!

From `$onderdeel['formInputOption']` To `$onderdeel['formInputName']`

My Apologies!

Comment: Good job, next time you will know how to systematically debug your program.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your `while` loop is faulty.

Should be something like:

```
$i=0;
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
    $result[] = array(
                        'id'=>$i,
                        'label'=>$r['label'],
                        'value'=>$r['value']
                     );
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: Aardig van je dat je dat er nog eff bij zet. Maar hoe ik het heb is namelijk op mijn manier, en dan begrijp ik het ook. en verander het liever niet! :)

Comment: Prima, ik zat alleen naar je `while` loop te kijken en zag dat het daar misschien ook mis gaat.